# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object with django Q query

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to filter Event objects to only show events where the event.day is greater than or equal to today. However, I get the following error when I run it:

`TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

views.py

```
today = datetime.now().day
availability = Event.objects.filter(Q(day__gte=today)).order_by('-day')
```

the day field in the Event model is a DateField. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

model.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    requester_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name="requester_user", null=True, blank=True)
    mentor_user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name="mentor_user")
    day = models.DateField(u'Day of the event', help_text=u'Day of the event')
    start_time = models.TimeField(u'Starting time', help_text=u'Starting time')
    end_time = models.TimeField(u'Final time', help_text=u'Final time')
    notes = models.TextField(u'Textual Notes', help_text=u'Textual Notes', blank=True, null=True)
    isConfirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = u'Scheduling'
        verbose_name_plural = u'Scheduling'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.start_time)
```

Comment: you don't need the `Q()` -> `.filter(day__gte=today)`, also, please post the model definition for Event, or at a minimum, the field type of `day`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently storing the entire date with year, month and day on your model, so you can't query it only using an integer containing the current day value, you need the entire date object or use a [lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#day).

To get the current day and query it on a `DateField` you should use `datetime.now().date()`:

```
today = datetime.now().date()
availability = Event.objects.filter(day__gte=today)).order_by('-day')
```

If, however you **need** to pass only the day you'll require another lookup:

```
today = datetime.now().day
availability = Event.objects.filter(day__day__gte=today)).order_by('-day')
```

Comment: thank you for the help. I had to use the second method because I'm storing the day value in a separate field. However, now I realized the issue with this. If today = "19", then that means even a date of July 10 will still be considered less than 19 and fail the check because i'm only comparing the day. If I get rid of the separate date fields and just used a start and end datetime field, would the first solution you posted work?

Comment: @winston I believe that if you want to filter by date instead of only day you should use the first method, it works with entire dates as, for example: Let's say today is `2020-25-12` and you have these dates (`2020-01-11`, `2020-24-12`, `2020-25-12`, `2020-01-01`) if you filter with the entire date using the first method only the last two dates will be returned.